# Why isn't this illegal character checking code working?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm using javascript to set up a download file system, 
[image]

But sadly it's not working. I narrowed down the errors to this snippet of code, which checks if the input contains illegal characters. I have already checked my HTML, its fine. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

JavaScript:

```
var file = document.getElementById("file").value;

if (~file.indexOf('..') || ~file.indexOf(':') || ~file.indexOf('?') || ~file.indexOf('<') || ~file.indexOf('>') || ~file.indexOf('|') || ~file.indexOf('"'))
{
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "<span class = \"err\">Link contains illegal characters. See <a class = \"sto\" href =\"prohibited.bmp\">this</a>.</span>";
}
```

HTML:

[image]

Comment: Can you build a snippet? We need the relevant HTML. And please use a regex to simplify this code

Comment: You should really consider using regex to validate input string instead

Comment: I dont know how to use regex. And i will give the full thing now

Comment: Everything works when I test the code you provided. What isn't working?